# Bootstrap error message issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Here is my code to validate gender radio button. I am facing a problem that validation message is displaying on top of radio button. Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
<div class="form-group">                    
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Gender</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" title="Select one">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the code, for how your are trying to validate. More the code, better we can understand your issue.

Comment: This is my jquery   
           gender : {
            validators : {
             notEmpty : {
              message : 'The gender is required'
             }
            }
           }

Comment: @GiridharGada please use the [edit] button on the question to add more code to your question.

Comment: Since it is a gender radio button, i suppose one of them should be check by default. Even if you decide not to, we usually validate as if($('input:radio[name=priority]').is(':checked')){}